# Cufon and jquery's slidedown

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cufon

I'm having trouble with IE, jquery's `slidedown()` function and the cufon script.

The website is http://thehealthagenda.com (its still mid development, so don't be surprised if its not completely finished!). At the top, on the home page, a panel slides down when the page loads using the jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#clinicianArea').slideDown();
});
```

On Firefox and Chrome this works perfectly fine, however on internet explorer this puts out the menu for some reason! I have no idea why this happens.

Can anyone shed any light on the matter at all? How I'm meant to fix this.

Oddly **unchecking** `display: inline-block !important` in IE's developer tools and **re-checking** it puts everything back where its supposed to be (that css property is on the `cufon` element).

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? And how to fix?

Thank you.

PS: If its something bleedingly obvious then I do appologise! But I cannot for the life of me find any explanation for this odd behavior!

Comment: Word of advice, change your doc type to be strict or use the HTML 5 doc type. You'll find that it will change how IE behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the parent element. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of assumptions:
1. try to add clear: both after elements in #clinicianArea and 
2. try to specify height of #clinicianArea element.

Comment: I see there is Cufon.refresh method, could you try it? I can't make it work in the console, maybe you'll be more lucky.

Comment: doesn't work... I'd already tried it. Also re-doing cufon.replace doesn't work either! :(

Comment: Ive added `position:relative;` to a parent div and it seems to have worked. :)